# Google Map API - Get Address of User

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, geolocation

Ive tried several methods to get get a visitors country location using geolocation method but im stil at no avail.

Could someone help atall as I'd like to get a visitors country and write it to a database using ajax.

my current code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script>
  var geocoder;

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
} 
//Get the latitude and the longitude;
function successFunction(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    codeLatLng(lat, lng)
}

function errorFunction(){
    alert("Geocoder failed");
}

  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();



  }

  function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      console.log(results)
      var country = results[7].formatted_address;
      $('.location').text(country);
      var dataStrings = 'email=<?php echo $userid;?>&location='+ country;  
      console.log(dataStrinsg);
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "location-update.php",
        data: dataStrings,
        success: function() {
            location.reload();
            }
      });
      return false;
        if (results[1]) {
         //formatted address
        // alert(results[0].formatted_address)
        //find country name
             for (var i=0; i<results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
            for (var b=0;b<results[0].address_components[i].types.length;b++) {

            //there are different types that might hold a city admin_area_lvl_1 usually does in come cases looking for sublocality type will be more appropriate
                if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "administrative_area_level_1") {
                    //this is the object you are looking for
                    city= results[0].address_components[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //city data
        alert(city.short_name + " " + city.long_name)


        } else {
          alert("No results found");
        }
      } else {
        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
      }
    });
  }</script>
```

Comment: Can you point to a live running version of the code or put up a JSFiddle that we can run? It's hard to debug all but the most simple code without context.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you call `initalize()` before the geocoding(otherwise `geocode` will be undefined):

You're accessing `results[7]` here:

```
var country = results[7].formatted_address;
```

...but there is no guarantee that `results[7]` exists.

Comment: initalize is loaded with the body tag. 

With Initalize running now it pops up "Geocoder failed" in an alert box :/